# Problem with repo sync while trying to sync a custom rom repo set

Tags: android, ssl, synchronization, repo

I am experiencing difficulities in manually building AOSPExtended (an Android custom ROM), and I need help with the `repo sync` command.

I initialized the repository list with `repo init` (of course), then, I started the `repo sync` command. Every time it tries to send a request to android.googlesource.com (SPECIFICALLY THAT), it fails, whether it is a TLS request or just a normal one.

Something that is worth mentioning, is that it tries to connect to android.googlesource.com using port 443, and it fails. Is there a way to change to port requested? (just interested, I don't think this is part of the problem).

Comment: Have you checked if your ISP/Proxy isn't blocking your 443 access? Try to connect into localhost:443 and if you succeed, then you ISP/proxy is blocking your requests.

Comment: Nope, it fails. It says "connection refused".